# In "Kotlin Notebook":: the command "%use lets-plot" does not find the library "lets-plot"

Tags: kotlin, plot, lets-plot

I'm new to Kotlin, but I really like Kotlin Notebook and I really want to build some kind of plot there.

For this:
1.In "maven" the project added the library "lets-plot-kotlin-jvm" version "4.4.2"
2.«Kotlin NoteBook Settings» → «Select Modules to Use in Notebook» → «Use all project modules»
3.«Kotlin NoteBook Settings» → «Select Project Libraries to Add to the Notebook classpath» → «Use all project libraries»
4.«Kotlin NoteBook Settings» → «Kotlin NoteBook  Plugin Settings» → «JDK Path» → «Project SDK 11»

Then I enter the magic command "%use" in Kotlin Notebook: and a drop-down list with libraries does not appear, for example, with the library "lets-plot".
 ***Question: Why?***

But if you enter the following code in Kotlin Notebook:

```
import org.jetbrains.letsPlot.LetsPlot
LetsPlot.getInfo()
```

Then it will be displayed on the screen: Lets-Plot Kotlin API v.Unknown. Frontend: Not available
**Question: Why is the version "Unknown" ?**

If you enter the following code in Kotlin Notebook:

```
%use lets-plot
LetsPlot.getInfo()
```

Then the "LetsPlot" object will not be found.
**Question: Why?**

P.S: Python3.11 + "Virtualenv Environment" + "System Interpreter" is installed on the computer
 (how could I, I'm new to Python)

P.S: At some point I received a message: «Initial dependencies for the Notebook are not yet provided. Consider executing any cell.» - which is not googled.

P.S: I have an IDEA under Ubuntu

**Questions:**
1.Why is no library found, including "lets-plot" when using the "%use" magic command?
2.Why is the "LetsPlot" object not found if using "%use lets-plot" ?

From Maven Central, I probably connected all the "lets-plot" libraries in which the word "Kotlin" was present, but the magic command "%use" still does not see the "lets-plot" library :-(

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you to file an issue on KTNB YouTrack? It seems it works as expected for me

[image: image showing a notebook with OP's actions done]

Comment: I have already created an issue on YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTNB-335/IDEA-crash-if-you-run-use-lets-plot-command)